# Return query from stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

someone has created a stored procedure complicated and now I need to see the query that is generated by introducing some parameters. I do not want the results, I just want to see something like

```
SELECT a, b, x FROM table WHERE OR ib ia = 1 = 2 some i ON LEFT JOIN xxx = yyy
```

The sp was developered on Postgresql =/

The last line says:

```
OPEN $1 FOR EXECUTE(lcQuery);
RETURN $1;
```

Can I do...?

```
RETURN lcQuery;
```

Comment: Is this a query that is genreated dynamically inteh proc?

Comment: Yes. According to the parameters entered a different query is formed.

Comment: execute it rather than returning from stored procedure

Comment: Just EXECUTE(lcQuery); ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this because type of `lcQuery` (i.e. `text` or `varchar`) differs from the declared return type of the function. Use `raise notice` instead, execute the function in psql and you will see generated notice:

```
...
raise notice '%', lcQuery;
...
```

Another option is to use a temporary table with a text column, insert value of `lcQuery` into the table inside the function and select the table after the function was executed. You can also use a custom configuration parameter in the analogous way.

Comment: This is exactly what I would answer and should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: There was a problem... nothing happens when I use RAISE NOTICE. I had to use `RAISE EXCEPTION '%', lcQuery;` to get the answer I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Did you test it in psql?